# coloring individual triangles in a vtkGlyph3D

Tags: c++, vtk

I created a new class `PieSource` (based on `vtkCylinderSource`) which creates a number of triangles together with the colors they should have:

```
int vtkPieSource::RequestData(vtkInformation *info,
                              vtkInformationVector **infoV,
                              vtkInformationVector *outputVector) {

    vtkInformation *outInfo = outputVector->GetInformationObject(0);
    vtkPolyData *output = vtkPolyData::SafeDownCast(outInfo->Get(vtkDataObject::DATA_OBJECT()));


    vtkPoints *newPoints;
    vtkFloatArray *newNormals;
    vtkUnsignedCharArray *newCols = vtkUnsignedCharArray::New();

    newCols->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
    newCols->SetName("Colors");

    newPoints = vtkPoints::New();
    newPoints->SetDataType(VTK_FLOAT);
    newPoints->Allocate(iNumVerts);

    newPolys = vtkCellArray::New();
    newPolys->Allocate(iNumTriangles);
    
   (-- here we create the triangles and determine their colors --)

   for (uint i = 0; i < iNumVerts; i+=3) {
        vtkTriangle *triangle1 =vtkTriangle::New();
        triangle1->GetPointIds()->SetId(0, i);
        triangle1->GetPointIds()->SetId(1, i+1);
        triangle1->GetPointIds()->SetId(2, i+2);
        newPolys->InsertNextCell(triangle1);
   }

    output->SetPoints(newPoints);
    newPoints->Delete();

    output->GetPointData()->SetScalars(newCols);
    newCols->Delete();

    output->SetPolys(newPolys);
    newPolys->Delete();

    return 0;
}
```

In my application i create a `vtkGlyph3DMapper` which uses the output of `PieSource`

```
vtkNew<vtkPieSource> pieSource;
pieSource->SetData(5, testData);     
vtkNew<vtkGlyph3DMapper> glyph3Dmapper;
glyph3Dmapper->SetSourceConnection(pieSource->GetOutputPort());
glyph3Dmapper->SetInputData(polydata);
//    glyph3Dmapper->SelectColorArray("Colors");
```

(`polydata` contains 2 triangles with colors -- without this InputData nothing is drawn)

When i run this, the glyph geometries are drawn in the correct places with correct orientations,
but they don't have the colors i have assigned them (all triangles are grey). If i uncomment the line `glyph3Dmapper->SelectColorArray("Colors");` the entire glyph is drawn with the same color (the one specified in the array named "Colors").

Is it possible to have a glyph whose triangles are individually colored?

If yes how must i do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, since your `newCols` array is empty, I don't know which color you are expecting.

Then if you want a color associated to the triangle, you should add your data array in `CellData` rather than in `PointData`. The array should have one tuple per cell (triangle here)

A small style remark: instead of `vtkXXX * myObj = vtkXXX::New();`, it is recommended to use a local-scoped object instanciated with `vtkNew<vtkXXX> myObject;`, so you do not need to `Delete` it.

Comment: ```newCols``` is not empty - it is filled int he part of code i omitted ("here we create..."). But the point is, i expected the triangles to have different colors.

-- and thanks for pointing out ```CellData```